# CSS to get multiple text boxes over image in various locations

Tags: html, css, image, captions

Here's my challenge: I have an image of a real property that will be loaded at random in a DIV 200 pixels wide. Accordingly the image will be resized to 200 pixels width and variable height (kept proportional). I have four separate captions that need to go onto the image:

1. Title
2. Price
3. Location
4. Surface

They need to be positioned respectively on the top center, bottom left, bottom left and bottom right of the picture. So I would have something like:

```
--------------------------------
|             Title            |
|                              |
|                              |
|Price                         |
|Location               Surface|
--------------------------------
```

I know that I can overlay text to an image by putting the div in relative position and the text in absolute position, but I only seem to be able to set one position for all text divs below, no matter how many classes I use.

Any advice??

EDIT: Found the solution. For reference, here is the code generated:

```
<div id="stampRandom">
    <img class="stampImg" src="myphoto.jpg">
    <div class="title"><span>Title</span></div>
    <div class="prix"><span>Location</span><span><br><b>Price</b></span></div>
    <div class="surf"><span><b>Surface</span></b></span></div>                  
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#stampRandom {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 80%;
}

#stampRandom {
    position: relative; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width:200px;
    color: #ffffff;
    /*    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 1px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000; */
    font-size:80%;
}
#stampRandom img {
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:200px;
}
#stampRandom div {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 200px; 
}
#stampRandom div span {
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
}
.title {
    top:2px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.prix {
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.surf {
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Thanks to all who helped out! I was blocked big time and my code needed a major redo. Fresh shot in the arm!

Comment: And what do you need from us to help you with?

Comment: Give us some code, geeza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/h51xLdzg/

```
<style>
.img-cont{position:relative;width:200px;}
.img-cont div{position:absolute; background:red}
.img-title{top:0px;width:100%;text-align:center;}
.img-price{bottom:0px; left:0px;}
.img-surf{bottom:0px; right:0px;text-align:right;}
</style>
<div class="img-cont">
    <img src="/MyImage.jpg" width="200"/>
    <div class="img-title">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="img-price">
        Price Location 
    </div>
    <div class="img-surf">
        Surface
    </div>
</div>
```

Think this will help you

Comment: This one was simple and worked for the sample. For some reason when I applied it with all my PHP tags I had to add "text-align:right;" to the img-surf class to get it to work.

Comment: Of course, I just missed aligning right-bottom (img-surf) div.
Edited

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick example of how you can accomplish this. It's not perfect but it works. If you need some other help or different approach let me know

http://jsfiddle.net/hg9r7/134/

```
<div class="imageWrapper">
 <img src="http://dummyimage.com/250x200" alt="1" width="250" height="200" />
 <div class="top">TOP</div>
 <div class="bot">BOT</div>
 <div class="botleft">BOTLEFT</div>
 <div class="botright">BOTRIGHT</div>
</div>
```

CSS example for bottom and bottom left text:

```
.bot{
 position:absolute;
 background:red;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
 width:100px;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-50px;
 bottom:0;
}

.botleft{
 position:absolute;
 background:red;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
 width:100px;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
}
```